# Automating datepicker for trivago.com with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am writing code to automate the searching of a hotel room, with specific check-in and check-out dates, and the number of people. I'm doing this on [Trivago](https://www.trivago.co.uk/), but am having trouble interacting with the datepicker element on the site.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

trivagourl = 'https://www.trivago.co.uk/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\conor\\Desktop\\diss\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(trivagourl)
time.sleep(2)
trivagosearch = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="querytext"]')))
trivagosearch.send_keys('mayflower london')

trivagosearch.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This code works for entering a destination name and hitting enter, which takes the user to the datepicker element, but because it's not a data input field in HTML I'm not sure how to automate it.

Comment: what is the issue you face while interacting with the datepicker?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish I'm trying to pass data to it through send_keys in a date format but it doesn't update it at all. I'm unable to click on any date element within it

Comment: It's not an INPUT field. You have to click it and then interact with the popup.